# AS3 Garbage Collection - Do non-dynamic children get this.parent reference?

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

By "non-dynamic children" I mean children of another library symbol pre-compile, eg, where a libray symbol MC_1 contains an instance MC_2 - MC_1 is exported for actionscript and MC_1 is addressed from it by using its intance name (lets say instance_1).
In this scenario, would MC_2 still get a this.parent reference to MC_1 that would tie it down and stop the garbage collector doing its business?  Would I have to (in MC_1's AS3 file) removeChild(instance_1) and set instance_1 to null?  Even if MC_2 wasn't given any references in the code?

What I've learned of garbage collection (in the 20+ articles I've read to no avail) tells me the answer is probably that I don't have to remove such references, but I ask because this is about the only thing I haven't tried.

I have a DocumentClass current_screen variable in the game that cascades a destructor() function through each class (most classes have their own destructor()) whenever the screen is changed (also removing current_screen from the display list and setting it to null).  The cascading destructors remove a class' children, ALL its listeners and sets all its object variable references to null (including those in arrays).  However the memory usage still steadily increases every time a new screen is created (current_screen = new Screen()), suggesting it's not being properly garbage collected (which eventually results in lag).  I don't know what else I can do in the destructor classes, except start removing purely graphical non-dynamic children out of sheer desperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be honest, I had a little trouble following your description, but hopefully I can offer some of my experience with garbage collection.

My experience is using the Flash Builder profiler.

As you probably have found in all the articles you have read, the key to effective garbage collection in flash is to make sure objects are de-referenced. This is achieved by:

- Setting the object to `null`
- Ensuring no other objects hold a reference to the object eg. `array`
- Removing any `event listeners` attached to this object
- Correctly destroying any `timers` or `intervals`
- Destroying any `tweens` that are working on your object

**The above also applies to any objects nested within the object in question.**

Using Flash Builder, my workflow would involve running the profiler and then doing a snapshot at a specific point in time then I would click the run garbage collector button. After waiting for the graph to update which usually proved garbage collection had run, I would snapshot again.

Next you can look at both of these snapshots and compare them, you will be able to see which objects are still around. If they are you can inspect them and try to work out what is holding on to them.

You are able to filter the class paths of all the objects to get to the ones you create more easily and if desired, remove built in classes if they don't figure in the objects you are trying to get to.

There is also a find loitering objects button but I've never relied on that.

As you don't have any control over when the GC is run (not in the browser at least), you can't guarantee WHEN it is run. So it's likely memory will increase and get collected when the GC decides, but if you profile with flash builder, you can prove to yourself using this approach that if objects are collected when you run garbagbe collection then it will also work when you allow the GC to handle it in its own time.

Comment: Looking back I agree that my description wasn't very clear - my apologies.  I basically meant Flash library symbol MC's that contain instances of other library symbols (ie, click-dragged in the Flash interface, as opposed to created by the code) - but that might be equally as unclear since you use Flash Builder.
The Flash Builder GC tools you mention sound like they'd help my case a lot - currently I'm just using Mr Doob's Stats.as class to monitor the memory, which is unspecific by its nature.  I've satisfied the bullet points you mentioned, so I'll give those tools a go - many thanks!